# R Create a variable with the levels of grouped data

Tags: r, dplyr, recode

I have a data frame such as `data`

```
data = data.frame(ID = as.factor(c("A", "A", "B","B","C","C")),
                  var.color= as.factor(c("red", "blue", "green", "red", "green", "yellow")))
```

I wonder whether it is possible to get the levels of each group in `ID` (e.g. `A`, `B`, `C`) and create a variable that pastes them. I have attempted to do so by running the following:

```
data  %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(ex = paste(droplevels(var.color), sep = "_"))
```

That yields:

```
Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
Groups: ID [3]

      ID var.color     ex
  <fctr>    <fctr>  <chr>
1      A       red    red
2      A      blue   blue
3      B       green   red
4      B       red    red
5      C     green  green
6      C    yellow yellow
```

However, my desired `data.frame` should be something like:

```
ID var.color     ex
  <fctr>    <fctr>  <chr>
1      A       red    red_blue
2      A      blue    red_blue
3      B       green    green_red
4      B       red    green_red
5      C     green    green_yellow
6      C    yellow    green_yellow
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need `collapse` instead of `sep`

Instead of dropping levels , you can just paste the text together grouped by `ID`

```
library(dplyr)
data  %>% group_by(ID) %>%
         mutate(ex = paste(var.color, collapse = "_"))

#     ID     var.color     ex
#    <fctr>    <fctr>     <chr>
#1      A       red     red_blue
#2      A      blue     red_blue
#3      B     green     green_red
#4      B       red     green_red
#5      C     green     green_yellow
#6      C    yellow     green_yellow
```

Comment: I have edited it. I used `collapsed` as well but it was wrongly. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same by using loops

```
for(i in unique(data$ID)){
  data$ex[data$ID==i] <- paste0(data$var.color[data$ID==i], collapse = "_")
}

> data
  ID var.color           ex
1  A       red     red_blue
2  A      blue     red_blue
3  B     green    green_red
4  B       red    green_red
5  C     green green_yellow
6  C    yellow green_yellow
```